# Limiting pages in php pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I want to limit the number of pages displayed on my pagination php script below.  This was a script made a few years back for me, and although I have read through similar problems on here, their coding is very different.

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Here is my current script:

```
<?php 
if ($max_pages>1) {
    echo "<br>";
    if ($page>0) {
        echo '<a href="'.$base_url.$sites_directory.($category_id==0?($page==1?'':($page-1).'/'):$category_id.'/'.$paginate[0].($page==1?'':'_'.($page-1)).'/').'" class="pagination">Previous</a>';
    }
    for ($x=0;$x<$max_pages;$x++) {
        if ($page<>$x) {
            echo '<a href="'.$base_url.$sites_directory.($category_id==0?($x==0?'':$x.'/'):$category_id.'/'.$paginate[0].($x==0?'':'_'.($x)).'/').'" class="pagination">'.($x+1).'</a>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<span class="pagination">'.($x+1).'</span>';
        }
    }
    if (($page+1<>$max_pages)) {
        echo '<a href="'.$base_url.$sites_directory.($category_id==0?($page==($max_pages-1)?'':($page+1).'/'):$category_id.'/'.$paginate[0].($page==($max_pages-1)?'':'_'.($page+1)).'/').'" class="pagination">Next</a>';
    }
}?>
```

Comment: who's Sarah? She keeps coming up in various posts :)

Comment: This is the first time I have ever posted on here, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Your current script cycles `$x` between 0 and `$max_pages`.

What you can do is first replace them with `$from_page` and `$to_page`:

```
$from_page = 0;
$to_page   = $max_pages;

...

for ($x=$from_page; $x < $to_page; $x++)
```

at which point the script will work just as before.

Now if you want to only display from `$N` pages before to `$N` pages after `$page`,

```
$N = 5; // display 5+5+1 = 11 pages

$from_page = $page - $N; if ($from_page < 0) $from_page = 0;
$to_page   = $from_page + 2*$N+1; if ($to_page > $max_pages) $to_page = $max_pages;
$from_page = $to_page - 2*$N-1; if ($from_page < 0) $from_page = 0;
```

Not the most elegant way perhaps, but it will try to fit an 11-page area centered on the current page. You may want to also display a link to pages 0 and `$max_pages-1`.

### MRE version

```
<?php 
if ($max_pages>1)
{
    $N = 5; // display 5+5+1 = 11 pages

    $to_page   = min($max_pages, max(0, $page - $N) + 2*$N+1);
    $from_page = max($to_page - 2*$N-1, 0);

    echo "<br>";
    if ($page > 0)
    {
        echo '<a href="'.$base_url.$sites_directory.($category_id==0?($page==1?'':($page-1).'/'):$category_id.'/'.$paginate[0].($page==1?'':'_'.($page-1)).'/').'" class="pagination">Previous</a>';
    }
    for ($x=$from_page; $x < $to_page; $x++) {

        if ($page != $x) {
            echo '<a href="'.$base_url.$sites_directory.($category_id==0?($x==0?'':$x.'/'):$category_id.'/'.$paginate[0].($x==0?'':'_'.($x)).'/').'" class="pagination">'.($x+1).'</a>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<span class="pagination">'.($x+1).'</span>';
        }
    }
    if (($page+1<>$max_pages)) {
        echo '<a href="'.$base_url.$sites_directory.($category_id==0?($page==($max_pages-1)?'':($page+1).'/'):$category_id.'/'.$paginate[0].($page==($max_pages-1)?'':'_'.($page+1)).'/').'" class="pagination">Next</a>';
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Hi Iserni, thanks very much for your help.  I am a bit confused as to what to replace within my original code.  Is there any posibility that you could edit my original code with the new code, just so I can see what you mean?

Comment: There you are. I left the explanation above, but it should be quite self-explanatory. You can try with different **odd** values for $N.